# How to handle internet instability in angular 8 app?

Tags: angular

I want to create a behavior that looks like Facebook.com behavior when it comes to the internet instability.

What happens in Facebook.com is that when you open a profile page for an example and before the data is fetched and displayed, your internet disconnects for some reason. After it comes back, Facebook automatically gets your data fetched without forcing you to refresh your page.

I am working on an Angular 8 project where the client may have internet instability like forever. I already used the `ng-connection-service` to monitor/detect the internet connectivity so I can notify the user once internet disconnects.

But what I need to do is to sort of store the http requests that cannot make it out because of the internet stop, then once it comes back they could be retried automatically.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Some ideas here... https://blog.angularindepth.com/retry-failed-http-requests-in-angular-f5959d486294